# How can I perform the HTML5 validation of an input tag using JQuery? Some doubts about this situation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I am pretty new in JQuery and I am finding some difficulties in the validation of an **HTML5** input tag.

So, in my page I have the following input tag:

```
<input id="variazioneAnticipo" class="rightAlligned form-control" style="width:50%" type="number" step="0.01" />
```

and this button:

```
<button id="variaAnticipoButton" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="validaProgetti()">Varia anticipo</button>
```

When this button is clicked is performed the following JQuery script that have to perform the validation of the previousinput field vi JavaScript (the inserted value have to be a **decimal number** and not for example a String).

```
$("#variaAnticipoButton").click(function() {
    alert("Variazione Anticipo");

    alert($('#variazioneAnticipo').checkValidity());

});
```

And here I have my problem because the previous JQuery script can't work, in the FireBug console I obtain this error message:

```
TypeError: $(...).checkValidity is not a function
alert($('#variazioneAnticipo').checkValidity());
```

but doing by JavaScript seems work, in this way:

```
document.getElementById('variazioneAnticipo').checkValidity();
```

I think that it could depend by the fact that **checkValidity()** is not a function of the object returned by the **$('#variazioneAnticipo')** JQuery selector but only of the pure JavaScript **document.getElementById('variazioneAnticipo')** selector.

Is it or am I missing something? I thought that both return the HTML element having a specific ID and that the **checkValidity()** function is applicable to this HTML object regardless of whether it is retrieved using JQuery or pure JavaScript. But seems which it is not so. What am I missing?

How can perform the HTML5 validation using JQuery instead the pure JavaScript in my code?

Comment: Yes you are right... `$('#variazioneAnticipo')` returns a jQuery object which does not have the method `checkValidity`.... which is a member of `HTMLFormElement` object

Comment: Hi Andrea, both returns very different objects. try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7386817/html5-form-checkvalidity-method-not-found

Comment: Try `alert(this.checkValidity());`

Comment: You can do `$('#variazioneAnticipo')[0].checkValidity()` - where `$('#variazioneAnticipo')[0]` will return the dom element reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#variazioneAnticipo')[0].checkValidity()
```

When you select `$('#variazioneAnticipo')` you get a collection of nodes, to access actual DOM properties you must select the first one.

Answer (score 4):

At the moment, jQuery does not have html5 validation api directly in their wrapper. But you can access the native object with this :

```
$('#variazioneAnticipo')[0]
```

So you can write :

```
$('#variazioneAnticipo')[0].checkValidity();
```

Comment: I guess you can also get it using `this` inside callback..

Comment: Yes it will works in callbacks. But not everywhere.