# Stop sending html form data onclick to javascript if there is validation error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created a contact form in `html` and `JS`. It has html5 default validations. But when i click on Send button form gets submitted with blank data and i receive blank email.and at the same time validations also pop ups. 
Want to stop sending blank form data. Please help. TIA.

JS code:

HTML:

```
<form action="" method="POST" class="form panel-body" role="form ">     
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" id="name" name="name" autofocus placeholder="Your Name*" type="name" required/>
        <class="form-control" id="nameError" style="disply:none;">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <span class="askfordemoalerts" id="nameError" style="disply:none;"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" id="emailID"  name="emailID" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$" autofocus placeholder="Your e-mail*" type="email" required/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="tel" " class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Telephone/Mobile Number*" autofocus required />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="companyname" id="companyname" required placeholder="Company Name*" rows="1"></text>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <select class="form-control dropdown" id="noofemployees" style="color:#555555c2" required>
            <option value="" disabled selected>Number of Employees*</option>
            <option value="1-9">1-9</option>
            <option value="10-49">10-49</option>
            <option value="50-99">50-99</option>
            <option value="100-249">100-249</option>
            <option value="249-499">249-499</option>
            <option value="500-999">500-999</option>
            <option value="1000-4999">1000-4999</option>
            <option value="5000+">5000+</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <textarea class="form-control" name="message" id="message" required placeholder="Message*" rows="5"></textarea>
    </div>                  
    <div class="form-group" style="color:#555555c2">
        <label> Contact me now<input type="radio" class="form-control radio" name="radiobtn" value="contactmenow" required onclick="contactmenow();"/><br>
        </label>    
        <label> Schedule a demo<input type="radio" class="form-control radio" name="radiobtn" value="scheduleademo" required onclick="scheduleademo();"/>
        <br>
        </label>    
    </div>      
    <div class="form-group">    
          <input name="date1" id="date1" class="form-control" type="datetime-local" style="display: none;"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" name="sendButton" onkeypress="$('#').text(''); type="submit" onClick="askfordemo();">Send</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

JS:

```js
function askfordemo(){
 var path = document.URL;
 var url = "";
       url = new URL(path);
 var frm = $(document.forms);
 var formData = JSON.stringify(frm.serialize());
 var name = $("#name").val();
 var emailID = $("#emailID").val();     
 var phone = $("#phone").val();
 contactDateValidation();
 var param = new Object();
 param.name=encodeURIComponent(name);
 param.emailID=encodeURIComponent(emailID);
 param.phone=encodeURIComponent(phone);
 var paramjson = JSON.stringify(param);
     path = path.substring(0, path.lastIndexOf("/"));
     $.ajax({  url : path + '/ms/askForDemo/sendMail',
   type: 'POST',
   data: paramjson,
         dataType: "json",
   contentType: "application/json",
   crossDomain: 'true',
   success: function(formData){JSON.stringify(formData)},
         error: function(x, y, z) {
         alert("Internet connection is lost. Please try again later.");
     } });}
```

Comment: where is your javascript code ?

Comment: @KirankumarDafda Added js code.

Comment: loose the type="submit" from button tag and handle the redirection code in js...

Answer (score 0):

jQuery/JS doesn't know anything about the HTML5 validation , so to check if everything is valid you can run like this :

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
    if($("form")[0].checkValidity()) {
        //your form execution code
    }else console.log("invalid form");
});
```

HTML5 validation will only work if you use classic html approach to sending data using form tags.

You can find more data on this on [W3C](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation_api.asp) also here are couple of similar answers:

- [HTML5 validation before ajax submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15713491/html5-validation-before-ajax-submit)
- [html5 form checkValidity() method not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7386817/html5-form-checkvalidity-method-not-found)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting form id like

```
<form id="form1" ... >
    <!-- all content -->
</form>
```

Just write down your whole code into

```
function askfordemo()
{
    var validator = $("#form1").validate(options);
    if (validator.form()) {
        // All code here
    }else{
        alert("Please fill all required fields")
    }
}
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'validate' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

You have to check if the data from the form are valid using `.checkValidity()` jQuery function before executing them further. `.checkValidity()` returns true if the data is valid.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form").submit(function(){
        if($("form")[0].checkValidity()) {
            alert('valid data');
            // do your operation here
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">

<form action="" method="POST" class="form panel-body" role="form ">  
    <div class="form-group">
     <input class="form-control" id="name" name="name" autofocus placeholder="Your Name*" type="name" required>
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-group">
     <span class="askfordemoalerts" id="nameError" style="disply:none;"></span>
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-group">
     <input class="form-control" id="emailID"  name="emailID" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$" autofocus placeholder="Your e-mail*" type="email" required/>
    </div>
       <div class="form-group">
    <input type="tel"  class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Telephone/Mobile Number*" autofocus required />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
     <input type="text" class="form-control" name="companyname" id="companyname" required placeholder="Company Name*" rows="1">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
         <select class="form-control dropdown" id="noofemployees" style="color:#555555c2" required>
         <option value="" disabled selected>Number of Employees*</option>
         <option value="1-9">1-9</option>
         <option value="10-49">10-49</option>
         <option value="50-99">50-99</option>
       </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
     <textarea class="form-control" name="message" id="message" required placeholder="Message*" rows="5"></textarea>
    </div>     
       <div class="form-group" style="color:#555555c2">
     <label> Contact me now<input type="radio" class="form-control radio" name="radiobtn" value="contactmenow" required /><br>
     </label> 
     <label> Schedule a demo<input type="radio" class="form-control radio" name="radiobtn" value="scheduleademo" required/>
     <br>
     </label> 
    </div>  
    <div class="form-group"> 
        <input name="date1" id="date1" class="form-control" type="datetime-local" style="display: none;"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
     <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" name="sendButton" type="submit">Send</button>
    </div>
   </form>
```